# Cross-posting in FAQs?

Tags: discussion

Anyone think it might be a good idea to have a link to The Great Outdoors in our FAQ, and maybe an equivalent in theirs, to try and help direct appropriate questions?

And if so, can you think of any other ones that may be suitable.  I'd consider linking to the proposal for the Immigration site, but unsure at present.

Thoughts and comments?

Answer (score 4):

See [Android FAQ](https://android.stackexchange.com/faq):

> Please note the following topics are expressly off-topic here:
>
> - Developing/programming for Android (please ask these questions on Stack Overflow)

So yeah, absolutely -- the purpose is to make people ask the question in the right place, because it will be migrated there anyway eventually, and saves moderator and high-rep users effort.

Answer (score 3):

The idea is fine. I see no problem when it comes to linking to a finished and well functioning site. I would be more reluctant when it comes to linking to a provisional site thing as the Immigration thing. Questioners will have a double disappointment: they get repelled on a well functioning site and are then sent to something less-than-half-finished.

Comment: I think it's a good idea to also link to beta and proposed sites - **as long as the info is maintained** and as long as it's clearly indicated which are established, which are beta, and which are merely proposals.